# Moving the left margin of text away from image

Tags: html, css

I have got text beside an image, but i am having difficulty with `margin-left`, Because it is not pushing the text 25px away from the images.

```css
.standards img {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 350px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.standard-main p {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="standards">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="">
</div>
<div class="standard-main">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus
    vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis
    imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit.</p>
</div>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhwX8.png)

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Well, `float` and margins have a complicated relationship.

What you could do is give the p a margin-left of 475px (the width of the picture and its margins, plus the 25px desired gap). But then the text in the p won't flow around the image any more. So in this case, the easiest solution is to give the img a right margin of 25px.

```css
.standards img {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 350px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right:25px;
}

.standard-main p {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="standards">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/400x350" alt="">
</div>
<div class="standard-main">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus
    vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis
    imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit.</p>
```